# Find artifacts in post-build actions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In a nutshell:

How can I access the location of the produced artifacts within a shell script started in a build or post-build action?

The longer story:

I'm trying to setup a jenkins job to automate the building and propagation of debian packages.
So far, I was already successfull in using the [debian-pbuilder plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/debian-pbuilder/) to perform the build process, such that jenkins presents the final artifacts after successfully finishing the job:

```
mypackage_1+020200224114528.NOREV.4_all.deb
mypackage_1+020200224114528.NOREV.4_amd64.buildinfo
mypackage_1+020200224114528.NOREV.4_amd64.changes
mypackage_1+020200224114528.NOREV.4.dsc
mypackage_1+020200224114528.NOREV.4.tar.xz
```

Now I would like to also automate the deployment process into the local reprepro repository, which would actually just require a simple shell script invocation, I've put together.

My problem: I find no way to determine the artifact location for that deployment script to operate on. The "debian-pbuilder" plugin generates the artifacts in a temporary directory ($WORKSPACE/binaries.tmp15567690749093469649), which changes with every build.

Since the artifacts are listed properly in the finished job status view, I would expect that the artifact details are provided to the script (e.g. by environment variables). But that is obvously not the case.
I've already search extensively for a solution, but didn't find anything helpful.
Or is it me (still somewhat a Rookie in Jenkins), following a wron approach here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [archiveArtifacts](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/). You have `binaries.tmp` directory in the Workspace and you can use it, but before execute clear workspace using `deleteDir()`.

Pipeline example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                deleteDir()
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'binaries*/**', fingerprint: true
        }
    }
}
```

You can also check https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/